# How is there a change in magnetic flux from a moving conductor through a uniform magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

My textbook states that when a straight conductor with a velocity perpendicular to itself and the magnetic field (see image), an emf will be induced between the two ends of a conductor. This means that there is a change in magnetic flux, but how is that so? According to the definition of magnetic flux = B*A, there is no change in either the strength of a magnetic field or the area perpendicular as the conductor moves through the magnetic field.

Could someone please let me understand why this is incorrect.

[image: conductor moving through magnetic field]

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483260/can-the-emf-induced-in-a-conductor-passing-through-the-magnetic-field-be-explain

Comment: Please try these: 1. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483260/can-the-emf-induced-in-a-conductor-passing-through-the-magnetic-field-be-explain 2. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/559888/emf-induced-due-to-moving-rod-in-magnetic-field

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> straight conductor moves perpendicular to itself

I don't quite get what you mean by this. But I think I understood the scope of your question.

In an ideal conductor it has an "infinite" number of free charges that can move. When a charge moves in the presence of a magnetic field it experiences a force given by $\vec{F_{mag}}^{\,}=q\times\vec{B} \, \,$, so this causes the the free charges to move (and this example it happens that the orientations will have the free *positive* charges move upward to one end). When the free charges do move, you have a difference in potential at the ends of the rod which qualifies as EMF.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand your reasoning here, which qualifies that an EMF is induced. However, as an EMF is induced, that means there is a change of magnetic flux. So how is there a change in magnetic flux if the area of the conductor and strength of the magnetic field are constant?

Comment: A moving charge generates a magnetic field, so when the free charges of the conductor move they generate a magnetic field, and since they are moving the magnetic field they generate moves with them, hence a change in magnetic flux.

Comment: I see that! Books gloss over those details.

Comment: This also begs the question then: if a conducting loop is considered instead of a straight conductor, will there be an induced emf/change in magnetic flux due to the magnetic force applied to the free charges within it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no change in magnetic flux, as you've said. What you're missing is, there is also **no EMF induced in any loop**. Try drawing a loop you think there is an EMF around. If a positive charge starts at the top of the conductor, goes to the bottom of the conductor, and then goes back to the top, it doesn't gain or lose kinetic energy. I think your confusion can be cleared up by remembering what the Biot-Savart law actually says: It says that changing magnetic flux *through a loop* results in an EMF *around the loop*. You've said there's no changing magnetic flux through any loop you can draw, and if you think about it there is also no EMF around any loop you can draw.

Comment: this is conflicting with what the other answer says?

Comment: @Max604 I don't agree with the other answer. This problem just has nothing to do with magnetic flux because it has nothing to do with emf around a loop.